# INSERT AND TRUNCATE

Tags: sql, database, db2, deadlock

In Db2 lets say we are inserting data in a table t1. At the same time another process tries to truncate data from the table. Will the truncate wait for the insert to be completed? Or will there be a chance of deadlocks

Answer (score 0):

You should request a table lock before you execute the truncate.

If you do this you can't get a deadlock -- the table lock won't be granted before the insert finishes and once you have the lock another insert can't occur.

You can use the LOCK TABLE command. The details depend on your situation but you should be able too get away with SHARED mode. This will allow reads but not inserts (this is the issue you are having I believe.)

It is possible this won't fix your problem. That probably means your insert statement is to complicated -- maybe it is reading from a bunch of other tables or from a federated table. If this is the case, re-architect your solution to include a staging table (first insert into the staging table .. slowly.. then insert into the target table from the staging table).

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd question any design where one process might truncate a table while another is inserting records.

Secondly, there's no chance of deadlocks given what you've described.  You might get a "object in use" message (probably SQL State = 57033).  But that's not the same as a deadlock.

A deadlock occurs when P1 locks T1 and P2 locks T2.  Then P1 tries to lock T2 while P2 tries to lock T1.  Both processes are now waiting on the other to complete before they can continue.  T1 and T2 could be tables, records, any resource really.

Even in a deadlock scenario, most processes should only be willing to wait a set amount of time for a resource.  Before canceling and trying again.  Deadlock is only an issue if both processes are willing to wait forever.  Now your RDBMS has to detect that deadlock and pick one process to kill.